# Center align multiple child DIV

Tags: css, css-float

I am finding it bit confusing working around this problem.

I have parent DIV and 3/more Child DIV.

Parent DIV is center aligned and child DIV should be floating left but should be aligned center.

**CSS** contains,

```
.center {
   float:left;
   height:250px;
   width:15%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[I have a sample of the code link here...](http://jsfiddle.net/wpXTr/)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want to horizontally align your elements centrally, then don't float them.

Change the way they are displayed to `inline-block` and align them in the center by changing the `text-align` style of their parent:

```css
#parent {
    text-align:center;
    height:450px;
    width:75%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.center {
    display:inline-block;
    height:250px;
    width:15%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1" class="center"></div><!--
 --><div id="child2" class="center"></div><!--
 --><div id="child3" class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Be sure to have no white-space or newlines between your children `<div>`s (in your HTML, that is) or comment it out. Now that these are *inline* elements, this white-space will be interpreted as a space.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the PITA-causing-whitespace. Haha, probably saved the OP asking another question.

Comment: I also took the liberty to edit out the A-word and format a bit. Hope that's okay with you.

Answer (score 5):

```css
#parent{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:row; /*default value is row*/
    height:350px;
    width:75%;
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding: 10px 0;/* not mandatory */
}
.center {
    height:250px;
    width:15%;
    margin:5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="child1" class="center">
</div>
    <div id="child2" class="center">
</div>
    <div id="child3" class="center">
</div>
</div>
```

Flex helps us achieve certain things with ease.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic margins will not apply to an element which has a float applied. Removing the float should get you started...

Answer (score 1):

### Center horizontally & vertically

Use `top` for vertically center and `calc` is calculating dynamically `top` value.
the top will work with `position - relative`.

Using `text-align:center` in parent & `display:inline-block` in child for Horizontally center.

```css
.parent {
height:400px;
width:400px;
position:absolute;
border:1px solid black;
text-align:center;
}
.child {
position:relative;
height:70px;
width:70px;
border:1px solid red;
top:calc(50% - 70px/2);
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">  
  </div>
  <div class="child">  
  </div>
  <div class="child">  
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```